# image sizes for different iOS devices

Tags: ios

I'm new to iOS programming. I want to ask these questions about image sizes for different screen sizes

1. Do x, 2x and 3x image sizes suffice for all the iOS devices? I mean if I have an image named "background.png", will background.png, background2x.png and background3x.png be sufficient for all the iOS devices/screen sizes?
2. If not, do different iPad models require some other image sizes(other than x, 2x and 3x)? ....... A link for explaining image sizes for different screen sizes/devices will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes x, 2x and 3x image sizes is necessary to develop application for all iOS devices , but the size of images can be different for iPad & iPhone devices, depending on your application UI for iPad & iPhone .

For better understanding for background images please have a look [Adaptivity and Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html)

One of the best article related to your query - [Adaptive Layout Tutorial in iOS 9: Getting Started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

If you made images for @1x, @2x, and @3x, name them like this:

- iPhone 3: `myImage.png`
- iPhone 4, 4S: `myImage@2x.png`
- iPhone 5, 5S: `myImage-568h@2x.png`
- iPhone 6, 6S: `myImage-667h@2x.png`
- iPhone 6P, 6PS : `myImage-736h@3x.png`

Then you can just call the blow method like:

`UIImage *myImage = [self deviceSizedImageWithName:@"myImage.png"];`

```
#define kScreenHeight [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
#define kScreenWidth [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
#define kScreenSize [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size
#define IS_IPAD (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE_4 (IS_IPHONE && kScreenHeight == 480.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && kScreenHeight == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && kScreenHeight == 667.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && kScreenHeight == 736.0f)

- (UIImage *)deviceSizedImageWithName:(NSString *)imageNamed
{
    NSString *imgExtension = [imageNamed pathExtension];
    NSString *imgName = [imageNamed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@", imgExtension] withString:@""];

    BOOL removedExt = [imgExtension length];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageNamed];
    if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        if (removedExt) image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-568h.%@", imgName, imgExtension]];
        else image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-568h", imageNamed]];

        if (!image) return [UIImage imageNamed:imageNamed];

    } else if (IS_IPHONE_6) {
        if (removedExt) image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-667h.%@", imgName, imgExtension]];
        else image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-667h", imageNamed]];

        if (!image) return [UIImage imageNamed:imageNamed];

    } else if (IS_IPHONE_6P) {
        if (removedExt) image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-736.%@", imgName, imgExtension]];
        else image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-736", imageNamed]];

        if (!image) return [UIImage imageNamed:imageNamed];

    }
    return image;
}
```